# .htaccess AddType json php with 1and1 hosting not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache, .htaccess

I'm working with 1and1 hosting and i have this javascript code

```
    $.post('main.php',{data:'somedata'},function(e){
           if(e.response==10){
           //process info
    }
    });
```

and in main.php i have this code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array('response'=>10);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The problem here is that i receive a text/html response and i need a application/json response in my XAMPP local server works perfectly, the problem is that i need to add the json MIME Type but the 1and1 panel doesn't have that option, i know that i can parse that response in javascript, but i need it in JSON format for a Web Service purpose, i tried using .htaccess with this code

```
AddType application/json json php
```

But doesn't work...

Comment: Can we have the link to check?

Comment: Have you considered using the longer `$.ajax()` form? That way you can specify return type. (`dataType`). PHP is only going to echo a string and that will not be treated like JSON until you receive it.

Comment: @HyderB. link: http://s671690758.onlinehome.mx/login/ use the form and put anything to receive the answer

Comment: @JayBlanchard the problem is, i use the same method for a REST API  in PHP so i need to solve this problem with php

Comment: REST API's, when returning JSON, always return JSON as a string, not an object.

Comment: @JayBlanchard check this link
http://sii.itnogales.edu.mx/ws_app/getKardex.php?nocontrol=11340833

if i delete the header('Content-Type: application/json'); my app don't understand that response

Comment: That is a string which looks like JSON, it *is not* a JSON object. Using `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX return *["Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object."](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)*

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok thanks for the answer, that solves the Web App part, but i need to communicate with a Android and a iOS app using JSON response just like the link a passed you and if Content-Type isn't application/json my app crashes

Comment: That is because your app is trying to evaluate a string as JSON. The app needs to receive the string and *convert* it to JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok i'm going to make your answer as the correct one, but if there's another way to solve this with .htaccess i appreciate that answer too... thanks for your answer and your time

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can you please post your first comment as a answer to mark it as correct?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the longer `$.ajax()` form. That way you can specify return type. (`dataType`). PHP is only going to echo a string and that will not be treated like JSON until you receive it.

Comment: I just do that and gave me an error 

ERROR 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Yes, in PHP using header('Content-Type: application/json');